# Simple forms fitting with java htmlunit

Tags: java, forms, htmlunit

So i'm trying to visit the website and fill sample form in it. After doing it manualy, the webpage is redirecting me to website with adress like this: *[http://wklejto.pl/[number]](http://wklejto.pl/%5Bnumber%5D)*, what I want to do in following code is:

- Writing something in form.
- Submiting it.
- Get the adress of webpage with uploaded text.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        WebClient webClient=new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        HtmlPage page=webClient.getPage("http://wklejto.pl/");
        HtmlElement samp=page.getElementByName("source20201129");//IT's updating daily in form: "source" + year + month + day
        HtmlForm form=page.getHtmlElementById("formwyslij");
        HtmlElement submit=form.getInputByName("submit");
        samp.click(); samp.type("It's Working"); submit.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        page=(HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println(page.getUrl());
        webClient.close();
    }
}
```

After running this code, the System.out.println(), prints:

```
http://wklejto.pl/index.php
```

instead of what i'm expecting:

```
http://wklejto.pl/[number of uploaded text]
```

Is it a bug? What am i doing in wrong way?

Comment: please open an issue on github - will have a look

Comment: Here it is: 
https://github.com/Szelwiga/HtmlUnitTests/issues/1 
If I posted it in wrong way let me know, I have never done in before.

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/272

At first i think it is no good idea to disable logging if something does not work - maybe there is a hint inside the logs helps you with your issues.

Have done some tests and it looks like there is some js-handler attached to the textarea that is required to finish before the click processes correctly.

This code works for me (maybe you have to increase the wait times depending on your machine)

```
    WebClient webClient=new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

    HtmlPage page=webClient.getPage("http://wklejto.pl/");

    //IT's updating daily in form: "source" + year + month + day
    HtmlElement samp=page.getElementByName("source20201205");
    HtmlForm form=page.getHtmlElementById("formwyslij");
    HtmlElement submit=form.getInputByName("submit");

    // samp.click(); // no need to click, type triggers the required focus events
    samp.type("It's Working");
     // wait a bit to let the textarea onkey handler do there magic
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(4_000);

    submit.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1_000);

    // get the current page from the window
    page=(HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
    System.out.println(page.getUrl());

    webClient.close();
```